# How to convert a large set of data in a multi line string into a table of values?

Tags: python

I have a lot of data in the form below:

```
19:27:39.829 -> 23.06,23.31
19:27:41.273 -> 23.06,23.31
19:27:42.717 -> 23.06,23.31
```

I want to convert these into the form below using python:

| Time Value | Temperature One | Temperature Two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.000 | 23.06 | 23.31 |
| 1.444 | 23.06 | 23.31 |
| 2.888 | 23.06 | 23.31 |

The time value is basically the difference between the value before the " -> " symbol and the uppermose value) In this case, it would be "19:27:39.829" - "19:27:39.829" for the top row, "19:27:41.273" - "19:27:39.829" for the middle row and "19:27:42.717" - "19:27:39.829" for the bottom row.

Temperature One is the value before the comma but after the " -> " symbol. In all three cases, it would be 23.06.

Temperature Two is the value after the comma. In all three cases, it would be 23.31.

I have already tried using lists and dictionaries but it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone please help me out with the code for this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the format of the set of data? is csv? text file? you can replace the "->" with comma and the read it as pandas

Comment: The format of the data is in text file + I don't know how to use pandas...

Comment: can you replace all "->" to comma? and change the format to csv.

Comment: Yup... I know how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for text file:

1. replace "->" with comma (better use findAll and replaceAll).
2. add first line: Time Value, Temperature One, Temperature Two
3. save the file as CSV

in python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
start = df.loc[df.index[0], 'Time Value'] 
df['Time Value'] = df['Time Value'] - start 

df.to_csv('result.csv')
```